# Eclipse can't connect to svn with ssh

Tags: eclipse, svn

I try to connect Eclipse (with Subversion) to my svn repository with ssh for a first import of my project. I think my repository is correctly configured on OVH. So, I have created a directory "svn", and inside this folder, I created a folder "test_repository".

When I try to right clik on my project and Team/Share project, I choose "SVN", "Create a new repository location". After that, I specify the Url "svn+ssh://loginFTP@mySite.com/test_repository. Then, I choose a new folder name ("trunk"), and after I specify "Use privet key authentication" and I select my key file and my passphrase, with port number "22".

When I click on OK button, I  guess eclipse trying to connect but it doesn't work. After 10 seconds, I have a message error :

> Error while creating module: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E210002: The connect() operation on the socket timed out.

I tried  some options in the "svn" configuration menu in "svn Interface/client" menu : SVNKit and JavaHL, but both doesn't work.

Last info: I don't use proxy.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does command line svn work?

Comment: Yes, if I try a bad url, I havent prompt with authentication, so it looking good